# {AWS} How to consume message parallel from s3 bucket in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have loads of files in S3 bucket, and i would like to process them parallel(ie: multiple threads)
Currently my program is like;

```
public Object handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context) {
..//DO processing
}
```

In the above code, I get single file each time. So launching multiple threads inside handle request would not make sense.

How can we parallely consume files from s3 bucket?

p.s: Im new to AWS .